# NodeJS and Express read JSON response in Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I am trying to do a simple server using Express but I am having a hard time reading the info I send to the client as part of the response.

This is one of my endpoints in the server:

```
app.post('/click',(req, res) =>{
    res.status(200).json({'message' : 'You clicked the button!'});
}
```

And this is the client that make the request to the server using that endpoint:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  fetch('/click', {method: 'POST'})
    .then(function(response) {
      if(response.ok) {
        return response.json()
      }
      throw new Error('Request failed.');
    })
    .then(function(data){
      var serverInfo = JSON.parse(data)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

And this is not working, tried a few more things like no using JSON.parse but still not working,
any idea on how I am supossed to read the server response in the client??

Comment: `'/click'` is not going to pick up on `'/test/success'` is it?

Comment: After editing the question and fixing the routes - what is the actual error you're seeing?

Comment: It's not an error, sorry If I didn't make it clear. The thing is I am not able to get a String in the client that has the value 'You clicked the button'. I don't know how to access the value I am sending

Comment: You `JSON.parse(data)`, although the `.json()` method already resolves to parsed data. `var serverInfo = data` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a quick look in the fetch you are calling the wrong endpoint.

`/test/success` instead of `/click`

Hope it will be that,

cheers!

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when writing the question :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo `return response.json` should be `return response.json()`. Try this.

Small note: dont handle error in in `then` block use `catch` block to throw error ; )

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  fetch('/test/success', {method: 'POST'})
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
    })
    .then(function(data){
      console.log('Do what you want => ', data)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when writing the question, did not solve the question :(

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `JSON` in the client using the following:

```
    button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      fetch('/click', {method: 'POST'})
        .then(async function(response) {
          const result = await response.json();
          console.log(result.message);
        })
    });
```

Comment: If you use `await` inside a function, you must declare it as `async`.